# Consulta con el máximo de ventas de cada mes

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

vengo solicitando su apoyo, tengo dos tablas: venta y detalle_venta, debo generar una consulta que me muestre la venta más alta de cada mes, básicamente necesito que la consulta me muestre: venta_no_factura, venta_fecha y el monto de venta, se que en los detalles debo multiplicar el detalle_precio por detalle_cantidad la cuestión es sumar eso entonces debo usar en algun lado max pero no logro desarrollar la lógica para hacerlo, muchas gracias por el apoyo, saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es la venta más alta de cada mes, sería:

```
 SELECT venta_no_factura,venta_fecha,importe
  FROM (
    SELECT *,YEAR(venta_fecha) ejercicio,
      MONTH(venta_fecha) mes
      FROM venta JOIN (
        SELECT venta_id,
          SUM(detalle_precio*detalle_cantidad) importe
          FROM detalle_venta
          GROUP BY 1
      ) c1 USING(venta_id)
  ) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(venta_fecha) ejercicio,
      MONTH(venta_fecha) mes,
      MAX(importe) importe
      FROM venta JOIN (
        SELECT venta_id,
          SUM(detalle_precio*detalle_cantidad) importe
          FROM detalle_venta
          GROUP BY 1
      ) c1 USING(venta_id)
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c3 USING(importe,ejercicio,mes);
```

En cambio, si lo que necesitas es el mes con más ventas, la estrategia cambia y las columnas que esperas como resultado también:

```
SELECT YEAR(venta_fecha) ejercicio, MONTH(venta_fecha) mes,
  SUM(detalle_precio*detalle_cantidad) importe
  FROM venta JOIN detalle_venta USING(venta_id)
  GROUP BY 1,2
  HAVING importe=(
    SELECT MAX(importe) FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(venta_fecha) ejercicio, MONTH(venta_fecha) mes,
          SUM(detalle_precio*detalle_cantidad) importe
          FROM venta JOIN detalle_venta USING(venta_id)
          GROUP BY 1,2  
      ) c1
  );
```

Recuerda que debes aportar el código de tus intentos para poder ayudarte a detectar lo que aún no sabes. Te he respondido porque al menos has compartido tu estrategia para plantearla y, aunque ibas bien con el planteamiento, te faltaban unos cuantos pasos que, sin intentar los pasos previos, no se te iban a ocurrir: las consultas se van resolviendo poco a poco, no del tirón. Analiza cómo la he resuelto yo, y pregunta todo lo que no entiendas, para después practicar y practicar con consultas similares hasta que te salgan.

Y siempre, siempre, aporta tu dataset en SQL para ahorrarnos el trabajo de generarlo a nosotros. Sobre todo para que los nombres de los campos coincidan con los tuyos:

```
CREATE TABLE venta(
  venta_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  venta_fecha date,
  cliente_id int,
  venta_no_factura int,
  venta_no_serie varchar(1)
  );
CREATE TABLE detalle_venta(
  detalle_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  venta_id int,
  producto_id int,
  detalle_precio float,
  detalle_cantidad float
  );
ALTER TABLE detalle_venta
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(venta_id) REFERENCES venta(venta_id);
```

Y, como última recomendación, inserta algún dato de muestra. Es mucho más fácil comprobar las consultas intermedias si los resultados van teniendo sentido. Cuando tengas soltura, podrás hacerlas sin datos, pero date tiempo, reduce tu nivel de exigencia y vete paso a paso, todo acaba llegado.

Quedo a la espera de tus comentarios para ampliar la respuesta de la forma que mejor te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sobre todo por los consejos que me compartes, veo que la complejidad de esa consulta es alta, jamás había hecho tantas subconsultas a la vez, me sirvío muy bien, de verdad muchas gracias.